# How to change/create custom FileProvider in .NET Core that's domain dependant (i.e. one web app serving multiple site rendering logics)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I'm currently creating a multi-tenant web app using .NET Core. And is facing a problem:

1) The Web App serves different **views** and **logics** based on a set of **domain names**.

2) The views are MVC views and stored in **Azure Blob Storage**

3) The multiples sites share the **same .NET Core MVC controllers** therefore only the Razor views are different with small logics.

Questions....
A) Is that possible?  I created a MiddleWare to manipulate however I couldn't assign FileProviders on context level properly because the file provider should be domain dependant.

B) Or, rather than thinking and attempting through FileProvider, is there any other way to achieve what I want to achieve?

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Do I understand your problem correctly: Based on domain name of incoming request URL, you want to render specific view, keeping one (universal) set of controllers?

Comment: Hi @CodeFuller . yes that's correct.  So all static files and razor views will be rendered based on the incoming request domain + url path

Comment: Have a look at Orchard Core and see how they solved it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The task you described is not quite simple. The main problem here is not to get current `HttpContext`, it could be easily done with `IHttpContextAccessor`. The main obstacle you will face is that Razor View Engine makes heavy use of the caches.

The bad news are that request domain name is not a part of the key in those caches, only view subpath belongs to a key. So if you request a view with subpath `/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` for domain1, it will be loaded, compiled and cached. Then you request a view with the same path but within domain2. You expect to get another view, specific for domain2, but Razor does not care, it will not even call your custom `FileProvider`, since the cached view will be used.

There are basically 2 caches used by Razor:

First one is `ViewLookupCache` in [RazorViewEngine](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor/RazorViewEngine.cs) declared as:

```
protected IMemoryCache ViewLookupCache { get; }
```

Well, the things are getting worse. This property is declared as non-virtual and does not have a setter. So it's not quite easy to extend `RazorViewEngine` with view cache that has a domain as part of the key. `RazorViewEngine` is registered as singleton and is injected into `PageResultExecutor` class which is also registered as singleton. So we don't have a way of resolving new instance of `RazorViewEngine` for each domain, so that it has its own cache.
Seems like the easiest workaround for this problem is to set the property `ViewLookupCache` (despite the fact that it does not have a setter) to the multi-tenant implementation of `IMemoryCache`. Setting the property without a setter [is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40917711/5740031) however it's a very dirty hack. At the moment I propose such workaround to you, God kills a kitten. However I don't see a better option to bypass `RazorViewEngine`, it just is not flexible enough for this scenario.

The second Razor cache is `_precompiledViewLookup` in [RazorViewCompiler](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor/Internal/RazorViewCompiler.cs):

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, CompiledViewDescriptor> _precompiledViews;
```

This cache is stored as private field, however we could have new instance of `RazorViewCompiler` for each domain, since it's intantiated by `IViewCompilerProvider` which we could implement in multi-tenant way.

So keeping all this in mind, let's do the job.

**MultiTenantRazorViewEngine class**

```
public class MultiTenantRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public MultiTenantRazorViewEngine(IRazorPageFactoryProvider pageFactory, IRazorPageActivator pageActivator, HtmlEncoder htmlEncoder, IOptions<RazorViewEngineOptions> optionsAccessor, RazorProject razorProject, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, DiagnosticSource diagnosticSource)
        : base(pageFactory, pageActivator, htmlEncoder, optionsAccessor, razorProject, loggerFactory, diagnosticSource)
    {
        //  Dirty hack: setting RazorViewEngine.ViewLookupCache property that does not have a setter.
        var field = typeof(RazorViewEngine).GetField("<ViewLookupCache>k__BackingField", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        field.SetValue(this, new MultiTenantMemoryCache());

        //  Asserting that ViewLookupCache property was set to instance of MultiTenantMemoryCache
        if (ViewLookupCache .GetType() != typeof(MultiTenantMemoryCache))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to set multi-tenant memory cache");
        }
    }
}
```

`MultiTenantRazorViewEngine` derives from `RazorViewEngine` and sets `ViewLookupCache` property to instance of `MultiTenantMemoryCache`.

**MultiTenantMemoryCache class**

```
public class MultiTenantMemoryCache : IMemoryCache
{
    //  Dictionary with separate instance of IMemoryCache for each domain
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, IMemoryCache> viewLookupCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, IMemoryCache>();

    public bool TryGetValue(object key, out object value)
    {
        return GetCurrentTenantCache().TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    public ICacheEntry CreateEntry(object key)
    {
        return GetCurrentTenantCache().CreateEntry(key);
    }

    public void Remove(object key)
    {
        GetCurrentTenantCache().Remove(key);
    }

    private IMemoryCache GetCurrentTenantCache()
    {
        var currentDomain = MultiTenantHelper.CurrentRequestDomain;
        return viewLookupCache.GetOrAdd(currentDomain, domain => new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions()));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            foreach (var cache in viewLookupCache)
            {
                cache.Value.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`MultiTenantMemoryCache` is an implementation of `IMemoryCache` that separates cache data for different domains. Now with `MultiTenantRazorViewEngine` and `MultiTenantMemoryCache` we added domain name to the first cache layer of the Razor.

**MultiTenantRazorPageFactoryProvider class**

```
public class MultiTenantRazorPageFactoryProvider : IRazorPageFactoryProvider
{
    //  Dictionary with separate instance of IMemoryCache for each domain
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, IRazorPageFactoryProvider> providers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, IRazorPageFactoryProvider>();

    public RazorPageFactoryResult CreateFactory(string relativePath)
    {
        var currentDomain = MultiTenantHelper.CurrentRequestDomain;
        var factoryProvider = providers.GetOrAdd(currentDomain, domain => MultiTenantHelper.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider>());
        return factoryProvider.CreateFactory(relativePath);
    }
}
```

`MultiTenantRazorPageFactoryProvider` creates separate instance of `DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider` so that we have a distinct instance of `RazorViewCompiler` for each domain. Now we have added domain name to the second cache layer of the Razor.

**MultiTenantHelper class**

```
public static class MultiTenantHelper
{
    public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }

    public static HttpContext CurrentHttpContext => ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;

    public static HttpRequest CurrentRequest => CurrentHttpContext.Request;

    public static string CurrentRequestDomain => CurrentRequest.Host.Host;
}
```

`MultiTenantHelper` provides access to current request and domain name of this request. Unfortunately we have to declare it as static class with static accessor for `IHttpContextAccessor`. Both Razor and static files middleware do not allow to set new instance of `FileProvider` for each request (see below in `Startup` class). That's why `IHttpContextAccessor` is not injected into `FileProvider` and is accessed as static property.

**MultiTenantFileProvider class**

```
public class MultiTenantFileProvider : IFileProvider
{
    private const string BasePath = @"DomainsData";

    public IFileInfo GetFileInfo(string subpath)
    {
        if (MultiTenantHelper.CurrentHttpContext == null)
        {
            if (String.Equals(subpath, @"/Pages/_ViewImports.cshtml") || String.Equals(subpath, @"/_ViewImports.cshtml"))
            {
                //  Return FileInfo of non-existing file.
                return new NotFoundFileInfo(subpath);
            }

            throw new InvalidOperationException("HttpContext is not set");
        }

        return CreateFileInfoForCurrentRequest(subpath);
    }

    public IDirectoryContents GetDirectoryContents(string subpath)
    {
        var fullPath = GetPhysicalPath(MultiTenantHelper.CurrentRequestDomain, subpath);
        return new PhysicalDirectoryContents(fullPath);
    }

    public IChangeToken Watch(string filter)
    {
        return NullChangeToken.Singleton;
    }

    private IFileInfo CreateFileInfoForCurrentRequest(string subpath)
    {
        var fullPath = GetPhysicalPath(MultiTenantHelper.CurrentRequestDomain, subpath);
        return new PhysicalFileInfo(new FileInfo(fullPath));
    }

    private string GetPhysicalPath(string tenantId, string subpath)
    {
        subpath = subpath.TrimStart(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar);
        subpath = subpath.Replace(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
        return Path.Combine(BasePath, tenantId, subpath);
    }
}
```

This implementation of `MultiTenantFileProvider` is just for sample. You should put your implementation based on Azure Blob Storage. You could get domain name of current request by calling `MultiTenantHelper.CurrentRequestDomain`. You should be ready that `GetFileInfo()` method will be called during application startup from `app.UseMvc()` call. It happens for `/Pages/_ViewImports.cshtml` and `/_ViewImports.cshtml` files which import namespaces used by  all other views. Since `GetFileInfo()` is called not within any request, `IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext` will return `null`. So you should either have own copy of `_ViewImports.cshtml` for each domain and for these initial calls return `IFileInfo` with `Exists` set to `false`. Or to keep `PhysicalFileProvider` in Razor `FileProviders` collection so that those files could be shared by all domains. In my sample I've used former approach.

**Configuration (Startup class)**

In `ConfigureServices()` method we should:

1. Replace implementation of `IRazorViewEngine` with `MultiTenantRazorViewEngine`.
2. Replace implementation of `IViewCompilerProvider` with MultiTenantRazorViewEngine.
3. Replace implementation of `IRazorPageFactoryProvider` with `MultiTenantRazorPageFactoryProvider`.
4. Clear Razor's `FileProviders` collection and add own instance of `MultiTenantFileProvider`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    var fileProviderInstance = new MultiTenantFileProvider();
    services.AddSingleton(fileProviderInstance);
    services.AddSingleton<IRazorViewEngine, MultiTenantRazorViewEngine>();

    //  Overriding singleton registration of IViewCompilerProvider
    services.AddTransient<IViewCompilerProvider, RazorViewCompilerProvider>();
    services.AddTransient<IRazorPageFactoryProvider, MultiTenantRazorPageFactoryProvider>();
    //  MultiTenantRazorPageFactoryProvider resolves DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider by its type
    services.AddTransient<DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider>();

    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
    {
        //  Remove instance of PhysicalFileProvider
        options.FileProviders.Clear();
        options.FileProviders.Add(fileProviderInstance);
    });
}
```

In `Configure()` method we should:

1. Set instance of `MultiTenantHelper.ServiceProvider`.
2. Set `FileProvider` for static files middleware to instance of `MultiTenantFileProvider`.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    MultiTenantHelper.ServiceProvider = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceProvider>();

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<MultiTenantFileProvider>()
    });

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

[**Sample Project on GitHub**](https://github.com/CodeFuller/stackoverflow/tree/Q47313612-MultiTenant-FileProvider)

Comment: I'm going to bend SO's commenting guidelines to offer a thank you for this. I don't have @lida-weng's requirements, but I am in need of introducing an additional replacement parameter to how `RazorViewEngine` and `DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider` handle view matching requests. Your exceptionally detailed answer provides a lot of insights for how I might approach that—and also empathy for the kittens. Thank you. It's unfortunate that your only payment for this is the 50 point bounty and a couple of upvotes; this answer required a lot of knowledge and effort to provide.

Comment: @LGSon - Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can check Saaskit here on this article for multitenancy

https://benfoster.io/blog/asp-net-core-themes-and-multi-tenancy

for locating views, you can follow @CodeFuller concept by overriding MultiTenantFileProvider

but in the you have to register it as below

```
     services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(options =>
        {
            options.FileProviders.Clear();
            options.FileProviders.Add(new TenantFileProvider());
        });
```