# Access properties inside a propertyinfo

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I need to set the Value property inside the BFrame class through the Tag class.

How am I suppose to set the **`Value`** property?

**Clarification:**
I am not trying to set the value of the **`Frame`** property inside the **`Tag`** class but the **`Value`** property of the **`Frame`** property which is of the type **`BFrame`**.

```
class BFrame
{
    string Value{get; set;}
}

class Tag
{
    BFrame Frame{get;}
}

public void func(Tag tag, string newValue)
{
    PropertyInfo frameProperty = tag.GetType().GetProperty("Frame");
    var oldValue = frameProperty.GetValue(tag);
    //frameProperty.SetValue(tag, newValue); //Doesn't work. Throws exception because there is no setter
    //TODO: Set the Value property inside the BFrame class
    //Somethig like this: tag.Frame.Value = newValue;
}
```

Comment: have you tried working with ? ` .GetField()` ?

Comment: If the property doesn't have a setter, you *can't* set it.

Comment: @Vulpex these are properties, `GetField` isn't relevant.

Comment: @Amy not trying to argue but can you explain to me? There should still be a filed, in this case an anonymous. There may not be a direct setter method but still there should be a way to access the field where the data is stored or am I completly off here?

Comment: @Vulpex Fields and properties are different things in C#.  These are properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set value of property where there is no setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665410/how-to-set-value-of-property-where-there-is-no-setter)

Comment: @Amy How is it a duplicate?

Comment: @RandallFlagg well the second answer is exactly your question.
ps.: Amy see what I said is written as answer there

Comment: @Amy Is correct, your property doesn't have a setter.  It is marked read only.

Comment: @Vulpex as I stated in my question there is only a getter. I want the Value property inside the value returned from the getter. Please see the accepted answer to understand what I asked and why the link you suggested isn't relevant.

Comment: Why even need reflection here? Why not just set `tag.Frame.Value` directly, or is this just a dummy example?

Comment: @RandallFlagg I did not suggest the link. The second answer from the link is the suggestion I made since it is the same, the property has no setter. `var field = typeof(MyClass).GetField("<MyNumber>k__BackingField", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)` is used to get the backend field from the property. `field.SetValue(anIstanceOfMyClass, 3);` is used to set the value. It should work with the example you've provided unless it is not accurate. If the value is processed and not stored, it may not work.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 My goal was to go over all the properties inside a class I have. I would love to hear of a different approach for achieving this. And yes, this is a dummy example :)

Comment: @RandallFlagg see my comment about dummy example. If the value is processed purely, there is most likely no backend field and therefore probably will not work.

Comment: @Vulpex Thanks for helping. The solution you offered with the backing field is not relevant as it doesn't solve the problem. Your solution returns the backing field but what I want to set is a property inside it. Please take a look at the accepted answer and at the line added in the question. It has nothing to do with the availability of the backing field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cast return value of `GetValue` to `BFrame`

```
var bFrame = (BFrame) frameProperty.GetValue(tag);
bFrame.Value = newValue;
```