# C#: Is there a way to access a private getter and setter?

Tags: c#, oop, private

I am new to C# and I am just wondering if there is any way to access getter and setter.

here is an example code:

```
public class Foo
{
  private AnotherClass _here;
  private bool Bar
  {
    get{return _here.GetAnswer();}
    set(return _here.SetAnswer(value);)
  }
}
```

I am aware that there is the Reflection feature in c# but as far as I have read, It only does private variables.

Also, I have been trying This code:

```
public void func()
{

  MethodInfo privMethod = Foo.GetType().
                        GetMethod("Bar", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

  object fff = privMethod.Invoke();

}
```

But it would not work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Yes. Reflection. Where did you read that it only does private variables? That's not true. Don't trust random nonsense you read on the internet. Confirm with MSDN.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219261/is-it-possible-to-get-a-propertys-private-setter-through-reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PropertyInfo property = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
MethodInfo getMethod = property.GetGetMethod(true);
MethodInfo setMethod = property.GetSetMethod(true);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for this answer! @Yarik